# Obtaining IndexReader using CloudSolrServer SolrJ 4.4

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud, solr4j

I want to use FastVectorHiglighter.getBestFragments(...) programatically.
In order to do so, i need IndexReader object for specified request.

Problem is that i cannot obtain request itself.
All that SolrQuery object provides is queryRespose.

Tried to create my own SolrCore object

```
CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(ZK_URL);
CoreDescriptor cd = new CoreDescriptor(container, "coreName_shard1_replica1",      coreInstanceDir);
SolrCore core = new SolrCore("coreName_shard1_replica1",cd );
LocalSolrQueryRequest localRequest = new LocalSolrQueryRequest(core,someSolrQuery);
IndexReader reader = localRequest.getSearcher().getIndexReader();
```

Although above(getReader()) results in null.
Would use some hints on: how to get indexReader with solrCloud.

Thank you in advance